# Why do dotfiles without extension appear as folders in Finder (Ventura)?

Tags: finder, ventura

I recently moved to a new Mac with a ***clean* install of MacOS Ventura 13.1** on an **M1 Pro**. I discovered that some files in my home folder show as folders in **Finder**, while still being files. I cannot get rid of it and have no idea, how that could happen.

> - It seems to only happen to files **starting with a dot** and **no extension**.
> - File **type** seems to be fine as there is **no chevron** next to the icon
> - It also happens with the **guest user**.

Thanks for any ideas or help!

- Am I doing something wrong?
- What could be the reason?
- How could I fix it?

#### Finder

[image: dotfiles without extension show as folder (Finder)]

#### Terminal

[image: dotfiles without extension show as folder (Terminal)]

Comment: Is the folder view from macOS Finder ?? - In the terminal view, you posted, the files are not shown as folders.

Comment: Yes, the folder view is **Finder** (added to question). Terminal is fine: Colors are OK and "d" property also shown. Finder even interprets the "files" somehow correctly as it does not show the chevron next to its icon. It only seems to be the icon itself.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (Ventura 13.1 on Intel Mac). Does your Mac have an Intel or an Apple Silicon chip? What version of macOS Ventura do you have?

Comment: I also use **Ventura 13.1**, but on an **M1 Pro**. I particularly _did not_ migrate my old user, because I wanted to start clean and not carry all the old stuff with me.

Comment: I just activated the **guest user** and the same problem can also be seen in that account. It seems to be a _system_ problem, but a _user_ problem.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode (hold Shit while booting). If it continues, it looks like a bug in Finder

Comment: **Safe Mode _did not help_**. I even rebuild Launch Services (with Onyx), uninstalled Dropbox, uninstalled OneDrive. No change whatsoever.

Comment:  I finally fixed it! Or: It fixed itself? While all of the stuff above did not give the icons back, calling `Command-I` actually **updated the icon**. The icons change upon opening the info panel. I also did this before to compare the files and see what might be different – without any result. Now, this seems to be the last step to fix it, because the icons might be cached? I'm guessing the Finder integration of Dropbox/OneDrive has something to do with it...